# Why Arch Linux is not booting using raspberry pi board?

Tags: sd-card, boot

I recently got my pi board and started working on it. I decided my first aim to install a OS image on SD card and boot from it. So i downloaded Arch Linux image file in zip format  from here http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads.

After that i installed **.img** file in my SD card Verbatim 8GB (I do not know why 4hr is also written here ?) using Ubuntu 12.04LTs . I used following commands :

1. sudo umount /dev/sdb1
2. sudo dd bs=1M if=/path/to/img/file of=/dev/sdb

After successful installation , when i tried to boot from it using PI board , then **my monitor shows NO SIGNAL** , i checked all the cables and i also borrowed another SD card from my friend preloaded with Raspbian , it was working fine, that is problem is with installation.So i again put SD card in my Laptop and i got surprised that it is not detecting it. I used Gparted , it shows unknown file system error.I again tried but the problem remain same .

Now my questions are :
How to install Arc Linux image in SD card ?
Why it is showing unknown file system after installing Arch Linux ?

Answer (score 2):

After loads of Googling, I am convinced that we are not the only ones with this problem and probably the problem is with the 2014.01 and 2014.02 image itself. I myself spent around 4 hours thinking I am going wrong somewhere. Downloading another image from http://archlinuxarm.org should help.